# grub rescue moved folder out of root

Tags: linux, boot, virtual-machine, grub, ubuntu-12.04

I made a really silly

> sudo mv /* /some_folder

move command on my remote server vm  ubuntu 12.04

that moved my boot folder to

> /home/.../somefolder/boot

I can access this folder via a browser terminal that gives me grub rescue.

How can I move the entire folder back to root location so to boot normally?

If that is impossible then if I boot from this location , will I be able to traverse to folders higher than the boot folder, as to at least copy my files via ssh?

Comment: What is a browser terminal?

Comment: Restoring GRUB won't help much in this case. You have moved your whole root to another folder.

Comment: @YtvwlD 1.Standard terminal -accessed via browser pop up 
2. Its not about restoring grub ,as to moving root folders at a higher level than the folders I need to access. This way I can boot ubuntu and just send my files via ssh.

Comment: Does `ls /` work in GRUB rescue?

Comment: @YtvwlD >Yes ls / does work

Comment: Why did you post it here and on Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't knew where this type of question fits better

Answer (score 0):

If you have direct access to this machine (perhaps via this browser terminal popup thing (?)), you could try to load your kernel and the initramfs and boot it.

This won't bring up your system again (because the boot process doesn't only depend on /boot) but you can get into a shell.

If you have full access to GRUB this may work:

```
linux /<path>/boot/vmlinuz<...>
initrd /<path>/boot/initrd<...>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. I know this can work but that way I won't be able to access files and folders in the directories above /boot.

Comment: Well, you can. Once you have booted the minimal system inside the initramfs, you are able to mount you file systems and do whatever you want.

Comment: Interesting .Gonna try out that and let you know how this worked out